# How do I merge duplicate values in a nested dictionary from a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a nested dictionary displaying the length between start and end points. Pandas is removing duplicate values when I want them to be included in the dictionary. This is the format I am trying to replicate:

```
graph = {
  'a':{'b':10,'c':3},
  'b':{'c':1,'d':2},
  'c':{'b':4,'d':8,'e':2},
  'd':{'e':7},
  'e':{'d':9}}
```

#input data from excel

```
> Delta X   Delta Y End X   End Y   Length  Start X Start Y

> 6.7098    0.0000  26.5740 10.8226 6.7098  19.8642 10.8226
> 4.8364    0.0000  19.8642 10.8226 4.8364  15.0278 10.8226
> 0.0000    -6.6551 15.0278 10.8226 6.6551  15.0278 17.4777
> 11.5462   0.0000  26.5740 20.4308 11.5462 15.0278 20.4308
> 0.0000    2.9530  15.0278 20.4308 2.9530  15.0278 17.4777
> 0.0000    2.6396  26.5740 13.4622 2.6396  26.5740 10.8226
> 0.0000    2.9530  26.5740 20.4308 2.9530  26.5740 17.4777
> 11.5462   0.0000  26.5740 17.4777 11.5462 15.0278 17.4777
> 0.0000    4.0156  26.5740 17.4777 4.0156  26.5740 13.4622
> 6.7098    0.0000  26.5740 13.4622 6.7098  19.8642 13.4622
> 0.0000    2.6396  19.8642 13.4622 2.6396  19.8642 10.8226
```

start and end coordinates read from the excel sheet attached are combined into a string separated by a comma. I want it to combine it to match the format. e.g.

```
'19.8642,10.8226' : {'26.5740,10.8226':6.7098, '19.8642,13.4622':2.6396}
```

It is currently replacing the first dictionary definition by the latest entry.

This is my output:

```
{
   '19.8642,10.8226': {'19.8642,13.4622': 2.6396},
   '15.0278,10.8226': {'19.8642,10.8226': 4.8364},
   '15.0278,17.4777': {'26.574,17.4777': 11.5462},
   '15.0278,20.4308': {'26.574,20.4308': 11.5462},
   '26.574,10.8226': {'26.574,13.4622': 2.6396},
   '26.574,17.4777': {'26.574,20.4308': 2.953},
   '26.574,13.4622': {'26.574,17.4777': 4.0156},
   '19.8642,13.4622': {'26.574,13.4622': 6.7098}
}
```

This is my code:

```
fromto = df.iloc[:,:]    
df['end'] = df['End X'].astype(str) + ',' + df['End Y'].astype(str)
df['start'] =  df['Start X'].astype(str) + ',' + df['Start Y'].astype(str)
fromto = fromto.set_index('start').T.to_dict('dict')
fromto = dict(fromto)
from2 = collections.defaultdict(dict)
nodes_list = []
for i in fromto:
    fromto[i].pop('Delta X')
    fromto[i].pop('Delta Y')
    fromto[i].pop('End X')
    fromto[i].pop('End Y')
    fromto[i].pop('Start X')
    fromto[i].pop('Start Y')
for start,v in fromto.items():
    length = v['Length']
    end = v['end']
    from2[start][end] = length
    for i in v:
        nodes_list.append(start)
```

Thank you!

```
'19.8642,10.8226' :{'26.5740,10.8226':6.7098, '19.8642,13.4622':2.6396}
```

Comment: Can you provide the example input data that would produce that output data?

Comment: I uploaded the table I am referencing to from excel

Comment: Your output doesn't really make sense, how to you combine `'19.8642,10.8226'`, `'19.8642,13.4622'` and `2.6396`?